# How to correctly import styles from an angular lib

Tags: angular, import

In my current project I want to create a lib container all different styles (`scss-files`). Therefore I need to import them into different components, so that the style will be set through these lib-scss files.

Importing libs into modules is quite easy by `@[projecttitle]/[libtitle]`

But how can I import only stylesheets? Something like 
`@import '~@[project]/theme/theme-to-import.scss';`
Does not seem to work.

I already tried importing like mentioned above, but that does not work at all.

Workaround right now is taking the relative path, but I think that won't work well in production mode.

Comment: "Production mode" is using compiled CSS files. You can use relative imports and it will work. Other than that, use the `angular.json` config file to add your styles to your main bundle. If you use `@import`, you gain access to the variables and mixins, but code optimization will remove the unused styles, whereas the main bundle won't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to put in `angular.json`

```
"styles":[
[project]/theme/theme-to-import.scss'
]
```

Put the correct path according to project folder.